# Using flashdata to determine if model was successful in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, web

I am trying to determine if the database Update performed in my model was successful, pass the status of it (successful or not successful) ultimately to my view so that I can display a div appropriately.  So far, it's worked as long as the model update worked, but it is not working when it's not.  I'm using flashdata to pass the data through the controller.

My model:

```
public function editTicket($ticket)
{
    $q = $this->db->where('ticketId', $ticket['ticketId']);
    $q = $this->db->update('tickets', $ticket);
    $results = $this->db->affected_rows();

    return $results;
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function editExistingTicket()
{
    $this->load->model('tickets');
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $ticket = array(
        'ticketId'    => $this->input->post('ticketId'),
        'category'    => $this->input->post('category'),
        'headline'    => $this->input->post('headline'),
        'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        'assigned'    => $this->input->post('assigned'),
        'status'      => $this->input->post('status'),
        'priority'    => $this->input->post('priority'),
        'lastUpdated' => $date
    );
    if ($this->tickets->editTicket($ticket)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('edit', '1');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('edit', '0');
    }
}
```

My View (the relevant parts):

```
var edited = '<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('edit'); ?>';

if (edited == '1') {
  $('#editMessage').slideDown('slow');
  setTimeout(function(){$('#editMessage').slideUp('slow')}, 3000);
  //sessionStorage.setItem('edit', '0');
} else if (edited == '2') {
  $('#editFailMessage').slideDown('slow');
  setTimeout(function(){$('#editFailMessage').slideUp('slow')}, 3000);
  //sessionStorage.setItem('edit', '0');
}
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the controller you are setting the flashdata to **0** if the ticket is updated unsuccessfully:

`$this->session->set_flashdata('edit', '0');`

But as you can see in the view you are expecting the variable **visited** to be **2**:

`} else if (edited == '2') {`

and then the error box will appear.

You should fix your values and i think everything will be fine.

Comment: That was actually just a copy & paste error.  The view is set for edited == 0.  When I Inspect Element, it shows edited == '' when the update failed.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Are you sure you are not making any request after set the flashdata? Except the redirecting to the view? Codeigniter flashdata is only available for the next request and after that cleared.

Comment: It goes exactly as the it does if the edit is successful, and that works, so it's got me baffled.

Comment: You can try to load the view directly, without redirect to see what is going on with that flashdata or you can also pass the result in $data. But i really cant get why it wont work...